# VLOOKUP Finding matching pairs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I currently am having issues using VLOOKUP to find matches within columns.

In column A I have Customer Names and in Column B I have corresponding phone numbers to each customer.

In Column D I have a List of possible customer names, and I want to populate column E with their phone number if ones exists.

The current forumula I'm using is:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$10706,2,FALSE)
```

Where D2 is the first 'Customer Name'

$A$2:$B$10706 being the Full range of columns A+B

Where index 2 is the phone number to return on a match

FALSE denoting that only exact matches be returned.

I Keep receiving an #N/A error even for exact matches I've gone through and manually found, and I'm not sure why.

Can anyone offer some direction?

Comment: Could you please give as a glimpse of your data? Screenshots maybe? Probably is data related. There is no exact match to be found or otherwise it should have found something. Please recheck your data.

Comment: Ar you positive there are no leading or trailing spaces? Without sample data it's hard to judge why this could be the case.

Comment: Hard to say without a sample of your data, given you are using exact matching have you checked for simple issues on the target like whitespaces/newlines?

Comment: Try equating your matches and see if it returns `TRUE` like `=D2=A35` where A35 is a supposed match to D2.

Comment: Sure one moment @Blenikos

Comment: Another quick debug test - Under the Formulas Tab, use Evaluate Formula on the Vlookup. It'll go step by step, and hopefully, you can see where it gets set to `False`.

Comment: I created a smaller sample with example data [here](http://imgur.com/a/vOyTm) since the original file is quite large.  It works on two of the elements, but in the larger dataset it doesn't work on ~any~ of the sets.

Comment: Formula Evaluation will not help in this case. VLOOKUP is calculated in one step and you will not be able to see why it fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem as far as I can tell from the screenshot you gave us  is that you have in one column numbers and on the other numbers stored as text (see the small green arrow on the top left side of the cell).

Double click the cell and then enter to make it from text to number and then vlookup will work.

To change the whole column and remove "number stored as text" from all cells you can do the following small "hack:

- Copy the whole column
- Go to an empty column Use
- Pastespecial->Operation->Add

[image]

Comment: Could also suggest using Value(D2) in his lookup formula so he doesn't have to do that for each cell. Good catch.

Comment: @Kevin You are perfectly right and I didn't thought of that!!! But in case he wants a more permanent solution for that without having to add in every formula the VALUE() function then I have edited my answer with a small "hack" that I have found really usefull from time to time.

Comment: Is there a simple way of extending the formula to the end of the column instead of dragging it down 12k+ rows?

Comment: Doubleclick the down right corner on the cell where your formula is located and it will go until the end ;)

Comment: Awesome thank you so much @Blenikos I've been banging my head against this simple function for the past few hours!

Comment: Glad I helped! I have myself lost many hours trying to find what is wrong with a single VLOOKUP in excel.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one :) Cheers!

Comment: @Blenikos Any idea why some of the values would show N/A, but when I reference my table and use CTRL + F I can find the matches?

Comment: I will need the data that cause the problem. Otherwise I cannot tell.

Comment: @Blenikos it appears the data I had received from someone else is missing values or is incorrect.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2*1,$A$2:$B$10706,2,FALSE)
```

That way you will convert to number within a formula.

Comment: That will not solve your problem if the "number stored as text" is on your range. There is no problem with the VLOOKUP itself to fix it. The problem is with the data itself. Also As proposed above in the comments there is a functino specific for that job: VALUE().

Comment: Small hacks like that will get you in more trouble in the future where you will not remember what you have done in the past.

Comment: I completely agree with you on long term, however, this solution is absolute match for the data provided and it requires no additional action from the user.

Comment: Use VALUE() instead of '*1'. It is safer that way both in short and long term and is far more elegant!

Comment: I appreciate your approach.
More elegant - yes.Safer - absolutely depending on what is your data and what do you plan to do with it.